# Does it matter if admin classes are located in models.py vs. admin.py?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm working through a (presumably) older Django tutorial and noticed that the customized admin classes for my models are located in models.py. In other tutorials they have been located in admin.py. My customized admin is working just fine, so I'm wondering why later Django tutorials extract admin classes out into a separate admin.py file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us some code, or we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`admin.py` is the more canonical way of storing admin classes. As the [`ModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin) documentation indicates:

> The ModelAdmin class is the representation of a model in the admin interface. These are stored in a file named `admin.py` in your application.

It may have been different in the past or your particular tutorial may have decided to do things differently. Either way it's better to move the admin classes to `admin.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Any tutorial with admin classes in models.py is not following the convention. The admin.py module [was introduced](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/releases/1.0-porting-guide/#the-admin) in Django 1.0.

Before Django 1.0, you defined an inner Admin class inside the model. Any tutorial doing that is completely out of date, and should be avoided.

Comment: +1 for tracking down which version made that change.